# Calling generic method with constraints using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, constraints

I use Reflection to retrieve the methodInfo from a generic method:

```
public abstract class BaseIdea {}    

public class ModuleBaseLogic {
  public void Sponsor<T>(int id) {
    // Do something
  }
}

public class Caller {
  protected static MethodInfo GetMethod<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expr)
  {
    return ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
  }

  public Caller() { 
    MethodInfo method = GetMethod<ModuleBaseLogic>(q => q.Sponsor<object>(id));
  }
}
```

This works fine. However if the method has constraints like:

```
public void Sponsor<T>(int id)  where T : BaseIdea, new() {
  // Do something
}
```

the `q.Sponsor<object>` (inside Caller) does not compile:

> The Type "object" cannot be used as Type Parameter 'T' in the generic
>   Type or method 'ModuleBaseLogic.Sponsor(int)' There is no implicit
>   reference conversion from 'object' to 'BaseIdea'.

I tried replacing it by `q.Sponsor<BaseIdea>` but that doesn't work either

Comment: I'd expect `q.Sponsor<BaseIdea>` to work - what problem did you see when you tried that? (The error you're getting with `q.Sponsor<object>` is entirely understandable, given that `object` doesn't satisfy the constraints.)

Comment: "'BaseIdea' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T'"
It *IS* abstract (and has to be)

Comment: Your generic type constraint is `T : BaseIdea, new()`, which means that `T` must be a type which derives from `BaseIdea`, which isn't abstract, and which has a public parameterless constructor. The type you pass has to meet all of those criteria. I suspect that either `BaseIdea` itself is abstract, or it doesn't have a public parameterless constructor on it.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with reflection. This is simply that when you write code which calls a generic method, you have to pass a type which meets all of the generic type constraints.

Comment: Thx. I did not provide the information that "BaseIdea" was abstract. Sorry for that. I added another class that derives from "BaseIdea" and used that as the Generic Type Parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work so far:

```
public abstract class BaseIdea {}    

public class ConcreteIdea : BaseIdea {}


public class ModuleBaseLogic {
  public void Sponsor<T>(int id) 
  where T : BaseIdea, new() 
  {
    // Do something
  }
}

public class Caller {
  protected static MethodInfo GetMethod<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expr)
  {
    return ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
  }

  public Caller() { 
    int id = 1;
    MethodInfo method = GetMethod<ModuleBaseLogic>(q => q.Sponsor<ConcreteIdea>(id));
  }
}
```

To give a bit of explanation:
Like Jon Skeet mentioned object can’t be a Generic parameter for any method with any generic constraint.
BaseIdea can’t be a generic parameter because it’s abstract, which is often necessary for a base-class.
The simplest possible Parameter is a concrete class, that derives from BaseIdea, which is given with my ConcreteIdea-class.
The new() constraint, as kara mentioned, needs also a parameterless constructor, which could also be the implicit one (default constructor).

Answer (score 2):

Here some examples, what is allowed and what is not if you got a `where T : SomeClass, new()`

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass { }
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass { }
public class MyClass2 : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyClass2(int x)
    {

    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass { }

public static void MyMethod<T>() where T : MyBaseClass, new() { }

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyMethod<MyBaseClass>(); // Does not work because MyBaseClass is abstract
    MyMethod<MyClass>(); // works because T is MyClass, which is derived from MyBaseClass
    MyMethod<MyClass2>(); // Doesn't work because it doesn't have a Std.Constructor "MyClass2()" it has a constructor with parameters "MyClass2(int x)"
    MyMethod<SomeOtherClass>(); // Doesn't work because T is SomeOtherClass, and it's not derived from MyBaseClass.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I took the freedom to modify it to match my problem. (It was MY fault, that  the "abstract" was missing in the question, not yours. But others who might end here should get the correct answer to my problem)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to use an expression that determines the name of the method by using the `nameof()` operator and then actually executing this expression.

```
public class Caller
{
    protected static MethodInfo GetMethod<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> expr) where T: class
    {
        // Execute the expression. We will get the method name.
        string methodName = expr.Compile()(null);

        // Return generic method information by name of the method
        return typeof(T).GetMethod(methodName);
    }

    public Caller()
    {
        MethodInfo method = GetMethod<ModuleBaseLogic>(m => nameof(m.Sponsor));
    }
}
```

Note: this will not work when there are several overloads of the method using the same name.